# Can't seem to fix errors in my function

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to create a function that will calculate a particular diversity index depending on the value of q. However, I'm getting a number of error messages when running it and I'm not sure how to fix it. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
q.div1 <- function(data, q, que)
{
  if(abs(q-1) < 0.000001)

  {
    # Get rid of zero values from vector
    no.zeros <- data[data > 0]

    # Calculate proportions
    p <- no.zeros/sum(no.zeros)

    # Calculate D1
    D1 <- exp(-sum(p * log(p)))
 }

  else if (is.infinite(q))
  {
    # Get rid of zero values from vector
    no.zeros <- data[data > 0]

    # Calculate proportions
    p <- no.zeros/sum(no.zeros)

    # Calculate D.Inf
    D.Inf <- 1/max(p) 
  }

  else if (q = 2)
  {
    # Get rid of zero values from vector
    no.zeros <- data[data > 0]

    # Calculate proportions
    p <- (no.zeros/sum(no.zeros))^q
    D2 <- sum(p)
  }

  else if (q = 0)
  { 
    # Get rid of zero values from vector
    no.zero <- data[data > 0]

    # Calculate proportions
    p <- no.zero/sum(no.zero)

    # Raise to power of q
    prop.q <- (p)^q
    D0 <- sum(prop.q)
  }

  else
    # Get rid of zero values from vector
    no.zero <- data[data > 0]

  # Calculate proportions
  prop <- no.zero/sum(no.zero)

  # Raise to power of q
  prop.q <- (prop)^que
  sum.pq <- sum(prop.que)

  # Raise to power 1/(1-q)
  pq <- sum.pq^(1/1-que)
 }
```

Comment: Please post your error messages along with steps you've taken to resolve them.

Answer (score 2):

The only error "my" R encountered was your "q" assignment.
When evaluating logical flags you should use **q==2** instead of q=2. This latter means that you are assigning a number 2 to the variable q.
Therefore modify your lines 28 and 38 by "**q==**...".
cheers!